# How to boot a USB 3.0 SATA HDD inside a Windows 7 Qemu Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, qemu

I have a Windows 7 VM, that I would like to recognize a SATA HDD that is plugged into a Voyager Q (USB 3.0 "enclosure").  I have tried various commands, and tried logging the output of the command with no luck.  I did manage to use a command that allowed the drive to be recognized in Windows 7 but only as a USB 1.0 device.  The drive is 3TB's and I am trying to run the Windows only Western Digital HDD test tool on the drive to see if it is good or bad, so suffice to say running an extended test on the drive using USB 1.0 would take the better half 24 hours.

Has anyone successfully got a HDD to mount within a Windows 7 VM using qemu, and if so what command / commands did you use?